# What data structure do Go maps use internally?

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm interested in the following:

- How are Go maps implemented internally? (hash tables, trees...)
- If Go maps are hash tables, which hash function is used?
- If Go maps are trees, are they AVL, red-black, or some other type?
- If Go maps are array-based, how do they avoid/handle collisions?

Comment: Please notice that regardless of what data structure Go uses internally, you should not rely on that. The data structure that backs a map is not part of the specification and may change without notice.

Comment: Note that "Go" is a specification, which currently has at least two mature implementations -- the so-called "GC" suite (what was initially created by folks from Google and is now considered the reference implementation) and gccgo -- a GCC front-end. One more thing to note is that the language specification does not enforce any particular implementation of maps and hence it can change from release to release in any implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go maps are hash tables internally

As @twotwotwo clarified in the comment, Go will use an AES-based hash if the CPU has supporting instructions for it.

Otherwise Go will use a [FNV hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) (As stated by Patrick Mylund Nielsen @ [Go-Nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/PY3CCBtbDsQ))

Links:

- Official Go Blog: http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action
- Map Source Code: http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/hashmap.c
- Hash Source Code: http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/alg.c
- GoNuts Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/PY3CCBtbDsQ

Comment: (This correctly answers the main question, but about the hash function used, Go [switched](https://codereview.appspot.com/7716047/) to use an AES-based hash on newer Intel chips for certain hash key types after Mylund's post. Submitted an edit to try to reflect that.)

Comment: @twotwotwo Ah, so it is. I wasn't able to get your edit, but I updated the answer with the correct information. Thanks for the info!